# Select last record after selecting top N

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select only the last record after selecting top N record. So in short I want to select only one specific record. I tried using subquery but it's not good. It gives an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

I know the subquery that I did gives more than 1 value but how to can I select the one specific record in a top N record?

```
select top 1 (select top 5 Work_date from tbl_dtr where work_date < '2019/09/10' order by Work_date asc) 
from tbl_dtr 
order by Work_date desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your subquery as a derived table and select from that instead:

```
select top 1 *
from (select top 5 * 
      from tbl_dtr 
      where work_date < '2019/09/10' 
      order by Work_date asc) t
order by Work_date desc
```

Comment: it worked sir. Thank you so much. But can i ask what is 't' for? sorry i really don't know what it is for and how it worked.

Comment: @troidevera When using a derived table (selecting from a subquery) it is necessary to give the derived table an alias (the `t`) so that (if you want to) you can reference columns from within it in the select (for example in this case you could use `t.work_date`). The actual name used just needs to be a valid sql identifier, I chose `t` as an abbreviation for `tbl_dtr`

Answer (score 1):

You can use offset and fetch next rows:

```
select Work_date 
from tbl_dtr 
where work_date < '2019/09/10' 
order by Work_date asc
offset 4 rows
fetch next 1 rows only
```

This way you are telling SQL to skip 4 records and return the next 1 row

Answer (score -1):

For an easier query you might also use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT Work_date
FROM tbl_dtr
WHERE work_date < '2019/09/10'
ORDER BY Work_date asc
LIMIT 1 -- only get 1 record
OFFSET 4 -- skip first for records, thus retrieving the 5th. Replace this with n-1
```

Comment: i tried to use your query sir but it gives an error "Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'."

Comment: To be honest, this is not real SQL-Standard, but most of the implementations offer keywords ```LIMIT``` and ```OFFSET``` (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Limiting_result_rows)).

I guess this way of formulating the query is much more readable, thus I would prefer it over the other, if it fits the used SQL dialect.
The ```SELECT TOP``` is also non-standard and (according to the linked Wikipedia article) available in fewer dialects.

Comment: @Islingre you've confused mysql with sql-server, read specified tags before posting an answer

Comment: @VasilyIvoyzha no confusion, there was no specification of any system. Please have a look at the version history of the question and find the edit of "a_horse_with_no_name" from "2019-09-07 06:17:51Z", adding "sql-server" and "tsql". It was just tagged "sql", you removed this later. (EDIT: And btw, this has nothing to do with mysql... I am more the psql type, but as mentioned, the LIMIT/OFFSET variant seems to be the most common one. If going for complete standard: use window-functions or cursors)

Comment: @Islingre yes, `sql` was removed by me because `sql-server` & `tsql` tags have been specified, two tags related to `sql-server` (from three existing) mean that exactly tsql required. In any case, this is your answer, and you decide whether should it be here or not, and whether it will bring help to the community or not, and whether it will be downvoited or not >>T-SQL (Transact Structured Query Language) is the extension of SQL functionality supported by Sybase ASE and Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this tag for MySQL, PostgreSql, Oracle(Pl/SQL) related queries.<<